# How to define a stationary point of the MINLP problem?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization, convex-optimization, minlp

As we all know, [KKT point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) and [stationary point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) are well defined when the optimization variables are continuous in the problem.

Now, I want to know whether there exist some special points except for the globally optimal solution in discrete optimization problems. For example, suppose $f$'s are differentiable with respect to $x$ for any given $y$.
$$\begin{aligned}\min_{x,y}\quad& f_0(x,y), \\
\mathrm{s.t.}\quad&f_k(x,y)\leq 0,\forall k\\
&x\in\mathcal X,\\
& y\in\mathbb Z.\end{aligned}$$
where $\mathcal X$ is a compact and convex set. Except for the globally optimal solution, what else do some special points (e.g. stationary point) exist? And how to define these points?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to OR Stack Exchange.

Your question is not clear. You are interested in special points in discrete optimization spaces. But you describe a mixed-variable problem involving both continuous variables $x$ and integer variables $y$.

For a given $y$, the theory of calculus of variations applies to the continuous subproblem on $x$. But I don't think you are interested in such a trivial answer.

If you're interested in the discrete part of the problem, the notion "local optimum" can be defined too, in an analog way defined for continuous spaces. Please have a look at [Polynomial Local Search complexity class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_(complexity)) definition and, even better, at [the seminal paper by David S. Johnson, Christos H. Papadimitriou, and Mihalis Yannakakis on this topic, namely "How easy is local search?"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000088900463).